# Click to jump to the line" does not work windows

Tags: texmaker

I do not wish to be redundant and i hope i am not. I have found a similar problem to mine here except the answer previously given here does not help me. 
It said

> maybe the problem is filename and filepath. No blanks or special characters are allowed!

But my filename is just "BA.tex" so no blanks and no special characters. Are there any other suggestions why it does not work? Plus it does not work on any of my files. Thanks in advance

Comment: Look again at what it says: filename and **path**.  A test can be to copy your file to `c:\temp` and see if it will work there (remember synctex also need to be enabled). If it does the path name might be the problem